# Simplification is not working for equations in SymPy Python

Tags: python, math, latex, sympy

I want to simplify this Latex equation in sympy

`\tan{\left(x \right)} \sec{\left(\frac{\pi x}{180} \right)}`
So I write this code to simplify this

```
import sympy as sp
expr = r"\tan{\left(x \right)} \sec{\left(\frac{\pi x}{180} \right)}"
expr = parse_latex(expr)

# Simplifying the expression
simplified_expr = sp.simplify(expr)
print(simplified_expr)
```

but the result is still like the input equation which was actually `tan(x)*sec(pi*x/180)`.So nothing changed by the `simplify` method !

I tried searching stack overflow and ChatGpt but everywhere I got only `simplify` method, which did not satisfies me.
The simplified version of the expression should be `tan(x)*sec(x)` this.
But the `simplify` method returns `tan(x)*sec(pi*x/180)` this.

Tried Sources:

1. [Expression simplification in SymPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620585/expression-simplification-in-sympy)
2. [Constant simplification in Sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75876880/constant-simplification-in-sympy)
   and many others.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated :)

Comment: *"The simplified version of the expression should be tan(x)*sec(x)"* <<< No, this is wrong. These two expressions are not equal at all.

Comment: SymPy's trig functions all take arguments in radians. You can use `pi/180` if `x` is in degrees but whatever definition is used for `sec` there is no way that `sec(pi*x/180)` would be equivalent to `sec(x)` so `simplify` will not make that replacement (and neither will any of the other simplification functions in SymPy).

Comment: Okay, I understand this. But what about this 
`- \frac{16 x \left(2 x^{2} - 1\right)}{\sqrt{1 - \left(8 x^{4} - 8 x^{2} + 1\right)^{2}}}`
even this equation is not simplified in sympy `simplify `
its simplified version should be `\frac{-4}{\sqrt{(1-x^2})}`
but simplify didn't do that !

Comment: If you substitute x = 1/2, the two expressions differ in sign (and are both real) so they can't be the same (everywhere).